# Replace single character in a String

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, tic-tac-toe

So, I'm using unity and I have this string that contains the current state of a tic-tac-toe board. It looks like that:

```
XOX
ONX
OXX
```

"N" being a neutral space.

The thing is I want to replace one of those "N" with either an "X" or an "O".
I tried using :

```
board[n] = "X";
```

but i get

> "property or indexer cannot be assigned, it is read only"

So I'm trying to figure a way to change one of those "N". Here is my code

```
if (manager.turn == 1 && !isUsed)
{
    xSprite.enabled = true;
    manager.board[int.Parse(gameObject.name)-1] = 'X';
    manager.GameEndingDraw();
    isUsed = true;
    manager.turn = 2;
}
else if (manager.turn == 2 && !isUsed)
{
    oSprite.enabled = true;
    manager.board[int.Parse(gameObject.name)-1] = 'O';
    manager.GameEndingDraw();
    isUsed = true;
    manager.turn = 1;
}
```

Comment: `string` is immuteable.  You'd have to do `board = board.Remove(n,1).Insert(n, "X");`, but you really should consider a different data structure like a 2D char array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Tic-Tac-Toe board is not a string, it is a 3×3 grid of markers such as chars. You should represent it as an array, not a string:

```
var board = new char[3, 3];
for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
        board[i, j] = 'N';
```

Then you can set each marker by its coordinates:

```
board[0, 0] = 'X';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 4 methods you can use:

**ToCharArray**

```
var array = board.ToCharArray();
array[indexOfNew] = newChar;
board = new string(array);
```

**StringBuilder**

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(board);
sb[indexOfNew] = newChar;
board = sb.ToString();
```

**String.Remove and String.Insert**

```
board = board.Remove(indexOfNew, 1)
    .Insert(indexOfNew, newChar.ToString());
```

**SubString and String Interpolation**

```
board = $"{board.Substring(0, indexOfNew)}{newChar}{board.Substring(indexOfNew+1, board.Length-indexOfNew-1)}";
```

Assuming `board` contains the original string, `newChar` contains the newly placed "piece" and `indexOfNew` contains the index in the string which you need to replace.

And you could of course wrap the option you choose in an extension method:

```
public static string ReplaceAt(this string inputString, int newCharIndex, char newChar)
{
    var newString = // Insert your choice of replacement from above here
    return newString;
}
```